# Using images inside components in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the image below for the background of a new app I'm working on. I'm trying to import the image from the web address directly, and the error I'm receiving says the browser is reading the ":" as the expected closing curly bracket to my src. Alternatively, I tried to call to a class that has my url in it from some sources I found online but that didn't work either. I'm a beginner, I tried to understand and troubleshoot as best as I could through material online but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The code to both will be below, Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './header.css';

class Header extends Component {
    state = {}
    render() {
        return (
            // url is underneath
            <img src={https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/130159.jpg} alt="background photo" />
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './header.css';

class Header extends Component {
    state = {}
    render() {
        return (
            // calling to class
            <img src={background} alt="background photo" />
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

---

```
h1 {
    color: pink;
    /*verifying my stylesheet works with my component, ignore*/
}

.background {
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/130159.jpg);
}
```

Comment: have your tried it with double quotes around the address? ("http:///..."). https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: Why not simply do: `<img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/130159.jpg" alt="background photo" />`?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I kept referring back to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/ and I never thought to add quotes around the url

Answer (score 0):

image src should be a string and you can't do this inside curly braces it is only for javascript things such as conditions, expressions and so more.

```
<img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/130159.jpg" alt="background photo" />
```

or you can make a separate react background component.